# Time limit Как оптимизировать программу?

Tags: java

```
public static void main(String args[]) {
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    int n = scanner.nextInt();
    String s = scanner.next();
    Queue<Character> queue = new LinkedList<>();
    Queue<Character> queueReV = new LinkedList<>();

    int length = s.length();

    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        queue.add(s.charAt(i));

    }
    for (int i = length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        queueReV.add(s.charAt(i));
    }

    int cnt = 0;

    while (!queue.equals(queueReV)) {
        if (cnt > length) {
            cnt = -1;

            break;
        } else {
            queue.add(queue.poll());
            cnt++;

        }
    }

    System.out.println(cnt);

}
```

Comment: Я подозреваю, что проверка на равенство очередей дольше всего выполняется. Добавьте в вопрос текст задания, чтобы нам не догадываться, что вы хотели реализовать.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проверьте еще раз предыдущий вариант, я его сюда выложила, но потом существенно его ускорила и поправила код прямо тут. Мне кажется он должен успеть в 2 секунды.
Ну и вот последний вариант, но, кажется, он медленный. К сожалению, других у меня нет)))

```
public static void main(String args[]) {
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
//  int n = scanner.nextInt(); // за ненадобностью
    String s = scanner.next();
    char[] chAr = s.toCharArray();
    List<Character> al = new ArrayList<>();
    List<Character> rev = new ArrayList<>();
    for (int i = 0; i < chAr.length; i++) {
        al.add(chAr[i]);
        rev.add(chAr[chAr.length - 1 - i]);
    }
    int cnt = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < s.length() - 1; i++) {
        Collections.rotate(al, -1);
        cnt++;
        if (al.equals(rev)) break;
        if (i == s.length() - 1) cnt = -1;
    }
    System.out.println(cnt);
}
```

Comment: А что такое rotate?

Comment: Так же выводит  неправильный ответ на тесте abac, должен быть циклический сдвиг элементов (перестановка каждого по очереди в конец) и выводиться 3

Comment: Да. Точно. Ошибочка. В самом конце строку `cnt = -1;` нужно заменить на `if (i == s.length() - 1) cnt = -1;` Я уже исправила здесь в коде. Та же ошибка и в предыдущем варианте. Кстати, вы его проверили на скорость. Как получилось?

Comment: rotate() - это метод класса Collections, который как раз таки и выполняет циклический сдвиг в указанной коллекции на указанное число позиций.

Comment: Выдается ошибка на тесте 4 в обоих вариантах, что за тест посмотреть не могу(

Comment: а в вашем варианте не было ошибки? попробуйте не комментить третью строчку, где n инициализируется... может в этом дело... возможно в тесте она учитывается

Comment: Не комментирую, не было

Comment: тогда, больше ничем помочь не могу... у меня все протестировано в IntelliJ IDEA... все работает... если бы знать, что за тест, можно было бы разобраться... а иначе никак

Answer (score 0):

Вместо двух циклов:

```
for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
    queue.add(s.charAt(i));
}
for (int i = length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    queueReV.add(s.charAt(i));
}
```

Можно написать один:

```
for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
    queue.add(s.charAt(i));
    queueReV.add(s.charAt(length - i - 1));
}
```

И можно убрать строку `int n = scanner.nextInt();` Переменная n вообще не используется.

Comment: Спасибо, но почему-то все-равно не проходит

Comment: должно выполняться не более 2 секунд

Comment: тогда лучше отказаться от использования коллекций... дайте полное условие задачи (а то по коду, как-то не очень понятно, что требуется) и я постараюсь помочь

Comment: Можно ли циклическими сдвигами развернуть строку s, еслиk -й циклический сдвиг строки – это строка, полученная перестановкой первых k символов строки в её конец. В частности, 0-й циклический сдвиг строки – это сама строка.

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте вот так пока, а я сейчас еще один вариант напишу:

```
    public static void main(String args[]) {
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
//  int n = scanner.nextInt(); // за ненадобностью
    StringBuilder s = new StringBuilder(scanner.next());
    StringBuilder sRev = new StringBuilder(s).reverse();
    System.out.println(s + " " + sRev);
    int cnt = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < s.length() - 1; i++) {
        char t = s.charAt(0);
        s.deleteCharAt(0);
        s.append(t);
        cnt++;
        if (s.toString().equals(sRev.toString())) break;
        if (i == s.length() - 1) cnt = -1;
    }
    System.out.println(cnt);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Не уверен на 100 процентов, но мне кажется, что это отработает быстрее всего

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String args[]) {

        char[] array = new Scanner(System.in).nextLine().toCharArray();

        int result = -1;

        for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
            result++;
            if (xxx(i, array)) break;
        }

        if (result == array.length - 1) result = -1;

        System.out.println(result);
    }

    private static boolean xxx(int i, char[] array) {
        int counter = i;i--;
        for (int j = 0; j < array.length / 2; j++) {
            counter--;i++;
            if (counter < 0) counter = array.length - 1;
            if (i >= array.length) i = 0;
            if (array[i] != array[counter]) return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

}
```